# Array referencing: adding an object to array of objects

Tags: javascript

This is probably a very basic question - see a simple code:

```
var ar1=[];
var ar2=[];
ar1[0] = 'Constant';
ar1[1] = data.attr.const;
ar2.push(ar1);  //OK, ar2 contains one array of two correct elements

ar1[0] = 'R-squared';
ar1[1] = data.attr.rsq;
ar2.push(ar1);   // Not OK - ar2 contains 2 identical arrays

ar1[0] = 'R-sq. adjusted';
ar1[1] = data.attr.rsqadj;
ar2.push(ar1);   // Not OK - ar2 contains 3 identical arrays
```

The problem is that every time when it executes **ar2.push(ar1)**, it overwrites all elements of ar2. After this code is executed, I get an obect with containing 3 identical arrays. How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Because you are re-using the variable ar1, perhaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objects in JS are always references (unlike strings or numbers). Whenever you `push` you're referring to the same object that is already inside the array, you need to clone:

```
ar2.push(ar1.slice(0)); // clone ar1
```